# how do define namespace and how does the compiler deal with namespace?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, namespaces

today i saw the C++ namespace,i suffer a problem.
what does the compiler does with namespace?
for example:
we write

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
```

then the question coming ,what is the relationship between the `iostream` file and the `namespace std`? and where is the `std` defined ，in what file? when i use `#include <iostream.h>`, i know the compiler will bring the declare from iostream.h like "cout", "cin".etc to my cpp file.

can you give some suggestion? thank you in advance.

Comment: Upvote and/accept the relevant answers

Answer (score 3):

read this, it explains about namespaces
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/

Answer (score 0):

`<iostream>` contains items from the `namespace` `std`. You can look at a namespace as a grouping of methods, class definitions and variables. Using namespaces makes them easier to group by functionality.

The `using` directive just imports all contents of the namespace in the global namespace. But you don't have to use it:

You can either use:

```
using namespace std;
cout << "whatever";
```

or

```
std::cout << "whatever";
```

The reason for this is that the compiler doesn't know what `cout` is outside the namespace.

Think of it as declared like:

```
//file <iostream>
namespace std
{
    //declaration of cout
}

//file <vector>
namespace std
{
    //declaration of vector
}
```

Comment: you say cout defined in std ,but what is the    #include <iostream> use?

Comment: i know,you meam every file like iotream string vector all have defined a std namespace, is it ?

Comment: @good90 yes... more like "extend" the namespace, but yes, that's the general idea.

Comment: There's also the possibility of `using std::cout; cout << "whatever";`.

Answer (score 0):

the situation is like you searching for something in a library. `iostream` is the book and `std` is the page and `cout` is the line or paragraph.

NB: the same page can exist in multiple books

read about [namespaces here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: Hmmmm... not really... unless the same page can exist in multiple books.

Comment: Well, the thing is the page `std` is not only in `iostream`, but also in `vector` and `list` and `map` and others.

Comment: hmm understood. so do u suggest some better easy understanding example?

Comment: I'd say that std is the book and iostream is the page. But this isn't much better either.

Comment: Leave out books and pages. anything other than that?

Comment: `std` is the encyclopedia, `iostream` is a volume (book) containing the article `cout`. Different volumes (books) can contain the the same article, cause the makers were short on hyperlinks.